# How to rename order status in frontend in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, payment

I need to rename order status in magento only for customers.

For exmaple:

Customer`s order has a status **"fraud"**. In frontend(for cusntomer) it should be displayed as **"Open"**, but in backand it should stay **"Suspected fraud"**

I use Magento 1.7. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `System->Order statuses`, edit the `Suspected fraud` status and you should have a separate field for each store view where you can input the translation for the status. Write `Open` for all of them (except admin - `Status Label`).